# Looping through Controls in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a chess program. And it is composed of sixty four picture boxes with alternating black and white background colours.
I have named them `pba1`, `pba2`, `pbb1`, `pbb2`, `pbc1` and so on.
Now, I want to loop through only the black ones, for example, I want to loop through only, pba1, pbb2, pbc3 and so on.
How do I create a loop for this in VB.NET?

I know of the way to loop through similarly named controls, but I am not able to adapt that method for my problem. Can you tell me a solution?

EDIT: In pba1, pb stands for picture box, and a1 stands for the square. Just in case, you wonder why such a name.

EDIT: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11168550/1453258)

Comment: Do you have model classes to represent the game state and board separate from the display logic and controls?  If not, you should.

Comment: Its winforms. And I don't have classes to represent game state. Its controlled by an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating controls at design time via the Forms Designer only makes sense for layouts which benefit from the forms designer.

In your case, you just have 64 uniform boxes in 8 rows of 8. Don’t use the Forms Designer for this, create the controls at runtime, and don’t give them names like `pba1`, just put them into an appropriate data structure (such as an 8x8 array):

```
Private chessFields As PictureBox(8, 8)

' In Form_Load:
For i = 0 To 7
    For j = 0 To 7
        chessFields(i, j) = New PictureBox
        ' Set size, position … then, finally,
        Controls.Add(chessFields(i, j))
    Next
Next
```

That way, you can access the fields in an orderly fashion without having to go via the `Form.Controls` collection.

Comment: +1. Step up to a more advanced programming level & follow this advice.

Comment: Yup. I will follow this advice! Thanks!!  
But another thing, if in this case, I have to access a picturebox, do I simply say, chessfield(i,j).BackColor=Color.Black ?

Comment: @Konrad I used this, but on loading, it is not displaying anything. It remains blank

Comment: Rohit, did you set the `Visible` property of the controls and give them a correct position?

Comment: I set visible to true. But I couldn't set the location. It couldn't be set. Giving an error. Dunno why.

Comment: @Rohit That’s not very specific. You probably tried setting `Location.X` and `Location.Y` separately, that doesn’t work. Assign it a `Point`, or set `Top` and `Left` separately. That won’t give an error.

Answer (score 6):

Loop through the PictureBox's in your ControlCollection and test for BackColor. I used the Form's ControlCollection, if they are in some other type of container control use that.

```
For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cntrl Is PictureBox Then
        If cntrl.BackColor = Color.Black Then
            'Do Something
        End If
    End If
Next
```

---

Base on the additional information that you gave in your answer, the reason your example is not working is that the Controls Name is a String and you are comparing it to the PictureBox Control not the Name of the Control.

You can try using the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) Property instead of the `Name` of the Control, it will be cleaner and easier to read. I just put a 1 in the PictureBox's Tag Property for Black and a 0 for White.

```
Private Sub OriginalColour()               
    For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
        Dim result As Integer
        If TypeOf cntrl Is PictureBox Then
            If Integer.TryParse(cntrl.Tag.ToString, result) Then
                If result = 1 Then
                    cntrl.BackColor = Color.Gray
                Else
                    cntrl.BackColor = Color.White
                End If
            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That does help, but in my program, the possible squares a piece can move has been highlighted. So after moving the piece to one of those, I want to return them to their original colour which will either be black or white. So I can't really check for the backcolor of the picture boxes. So any other solution?

Comment: this gives me an exception when I try it out.

Comment: @RohitShinde What is the exception

Comment: @RohitShinde See edit, it was hiccuping on non picturebox controls.

Comment: The exception is that system.windows.form.button cannot be converted to system.windows.form.picturebox

Comment: @RohitShinde Thats what I get for not running my example. I just added another example based on your additional information. I did run it this time :)

Answer (score 1):

Put all the pictureboxes in an 8x8 tableLayoutPanel (also useful for scaling etc). Then

```
    For Each pb As PictureBox In TableLayoutPanel1.Controls
        Dim col As Integer = TableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(pb).Column
        Dim row As Integer = TableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(pb).Row
        If col Mod 2 = 0 Xor row Mod 2 = 0 Then
            pb.BackColor = Color.Black
        Else
            pb.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    Next
```

Of course you could also use an array of the squares if you have that available.

This will not affect the events (pba1.click etc).

Comment: Will this affect my click events which I have already coded? I mean, I have already written some code for all the picture boxes. So if I put my picture boxes in a tableLayoutPanel, will the code or its functioning be affected? –

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple and it may be resource heavy, but it works. I have a form with 36 CheckBoxes. This takes advantage of the fact that when you copy a checkbox it just increases the number of the name. I ended up with 36 checkboxes named CheckBox1 thru Checkbox36. The Function returns a checkbox, which may be used to set or read any property.

```
Private Function GetCheckBox(ByVal Index As Integer) As CheckBox
    Dim CKBox As checkbox
    For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cntrl Is CheckBox Then
            CKBox = cntrl
            If CKBox.Name = "CheckBox" & Index Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return ckbox
End Function
```